# How to know in my API when a user cancel recurring payment in the Paypal interface?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm building an app that let people subscribe to my service and I use the Paypal Classic API. I'm stuck in one last thing, which is how do I know if a user CANCELs his recurring payment not from my app, but from his Paypal interface?

I checked the documentation here (last subject in the page): 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/

But all it says is that I can call `GetTransactionDetails` to check if a user is still paying. But it doesn't make sense: if you have 100 000 users, you can't run `GetTransactionDetails` 100 000 times every night to check if users are still subscribed?

What am I missing?

Is there a simple URL I can give Paypal so that if a user cancel from Paypal interface, Paypal call a page on my site that alert me of that on a per-user basis?

Comment: Why don't you check `GetTransactionDetails` when the user logs in? That way you're not running 100,000 calls to the function. You're only running it once when the user log ins. This ensures that the subscription is active before allowing the user to proceed. This way too, it doesn't matter how the user cancels the subscription. All that matters is if the subscription is no longer active, the user is no longer allowed access.

Comment: Hum... that's way better. But there has to be a better way? I'm surely not the first one with this problem. I'm currently reading about IPN (Instant Payment Notification) which could be what i need...

Comment: Yes, IPN is exactly what you want.